# Using bitwise operations for finding octant of point in 3D euclidean coordinate grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

We were given this monstrosity of a function that takes a list of 3D points, and returns a list of 8 values corresponding to how many points in the list occupy each octant of a euclidean three-dimensional coordinate system.

```py
from numba import jit
import numpy
import time

@jit(nopython=True)
def OctantPopCount(points):
    assert points.shape[1] == 3
    counters = numpy.zeros(8, dtype=numpy.uint32)

    for p in points:
        if p[0]<0 and p[1]<0 and p[2]<0:
            counters[7] += 1
        elif p[0]<0 and p[1]<0 and not p[2]<0:
            counters[6] += 1
        elif p[0]<0 and not p[1]<0 and p[2]<0:
            counters[5] += 1
        elif p[0]<0 and not p[1]<0 and not p[2]<0:
            counters[4] += 1
        elif not p[0]<0 and p[1]<0 and p[2]<0:
            counters[3] += 1
        elif not p[0]<0 and p[1]<0 and not p[2]<0:
            counters[2] += 1
        elif not p[0]<0 and not p[1]<0 and p[2]<0:
            counters[1] += 1
        else:
            counters[0] += 1
    
    return counters
```

The task was to write a function that does the same task as the function above, but without using any `if` statements. Here's my solution:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def octant_count(points):
    assert points.shape[1] == 3
    counters = numpy.zeros(8, dtype=numpy.uint32)

    for point in points:
        x_bit = int(point[0] >= 0) << 0
        y_bit = int(point[1] >= 0) << 1
        z_bit = int(point[2] >= 0) << 2

        octant = x_bit | y_bit | z_bit
        counters[octant] += 1

    return counters
```

For instance, given a point p = `(1,1,1)`, we find the sign of each component, bitshift them to the correct position, OR them together into an 8-bit number, and increment the value at the index of that number. In the context of p = `(1,1,1)`, the octant will be `0b00000111`, which in decimal is 7, so any point with all-positive components will be put in the 7th octant. What I want to fix is where the points are put in our counters variable.

In the function `OctantPopCount()`, a point with all positive components is placed in the first octant, while mine puts them in the 7th.

What are some approaches I can take to my implementation to fix this issue?

For some more context, here's the output for the functions, there's only a small difference between them.

```
points = numpy.random.random_sample((2000000, 3)) - 0.5
c1 = testOctantPopCountFunction(points, OctantPopCount)
c2 = testOctantPopCountFunction(points, octant_count)

print(points)

print(c1)
print(c2)
```

```
~/Code/Python/03 $ python3 octant.py 

Testing : OctantPopCount()
Elapsed time: 0.592 seconds

Testing : octant_count()
Elapsed time: 0.103 seconds
[[-0.4797098  -0.21997829  0.09571134]
 [-0.37825091 -0.19411628 -0.11625388]
 [ 0.06619321 -0.08700517  0.13289992]
 ...
 [-0.36272187  0.15922689  0.49523957]
 [-0.28635198  0.26316548  0.38360014]
 [-0.06738298 -0.49668077  0.25451539]]
[249036 250663 250512 250304 248926 249827 250275 250457]
[250304 249827 250663 250275 250512 248926 249036 250457]
```

Edit:
Here's what ended up working, thank you to Michael Butscher for pointing out that I had to swap my 0th and second index. Here's the updated code, along with the result:

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def octant_count(points):
    assert points.shape[1] == 3
    counters = numpy.zeros(8, dtype=numpy.uint32)

    for point in points:
        x_bit = int(point[0] <= 0) << 2
        y_bit = int(point[1] <= 0) << 1
        z_bit = int(point[2] <= 0) << 0

        octant = x_bit | y_bit | z_bit
        counters[octant] += 1

    return counters
```

```
Testing : OctantPopCount()
Elapsed time: 0.604 seconds

Testing : octant_count()
Elapsed time: 0.103 seconds
[[ 0.05981696 -0.08365013 -0.1045997 ]
 [ 0.02443854  0.08834479  0.29052881]
 [-0.21792648  0.43560819 -0.03026412]
 ...
 [ 0.39456249  0.19419522  0.3100608 ]
 [-0.07657673  0.32627312  0.00498049]
 [ 0.01845389 -0.26335805 -0.28143975]]
[249589 249817 249841 250896 249975 250613 249641 249628]
[249589 249817 249841 250896 249975 250613 249641 249628]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the same comparisons as in the original. (Also, make sure the `x` bit is the *high*-order bit in the result.)

```
for point in points:
        x_bit = int(point[0] < 0) << 2
        y_bit = int(point[1] < 0) << 1
        z_bit = int(point[2] < 0) << 0

        octant = x_bit | y_bit | z_bit
        counters[octant] += 1
```

Comment: While this does seem to result in a lot more of the points being put in the correct octant, a few of the octants are still incorrect.

Comment: I don't see how that could be.  You should show us some examples that fail.

Comment: @SinanPasic Right, indexes 0 and 2 of `point` must be switched (or the related bit shift values).

Comment: The only difference between this code and your original is how it handles 0 coordinates. If a point is on an axis, it really shouldn't be assigned to *any* octant, but depending on how you want assign on-axis points to an octant, you might try `<=` instead of `<`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Oh, right. I've adjusted the shifts.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I appreciate it a lot, I've been hesitant to post questions on SO, but this was a helpful experience. Thanks to everyone who helped!